# Define generic types dependant on each other `map: Map<T, (<T>(params: Partial<T>) => T)>;`

Tags: typescript, generics

I need a Map where the `key` of the map is equal the returning type of the function which is the `value`. How could i define this? The syntax like in the example is wrong, but i would try to explain.

`Map<key, value>`

- `key` is type `T`
- `value` is a function accepting on parameter of type `Partial<T>` and returning `T`

```js
export class DeserializerService {

  private readonly map: Map<T, (<T>(params: Partial<T>) => T)> = new Map();

  constructor() {
    this.initMap();
  }

  public getDeserializeFunction(type: T): T {
    const func: Function | undefined = this.map.get(type);
    if (!func) {
      throw new Error(`No deserializer found for ${type.name}`);
    }
    return func;
  }

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map.set(Vector2, (params: Partial<Vector2>) => new Vector2(params.x, params.y));
    this.map.set(Vector3, (params: Partial<Vector3>) => new Vector3(params.x, params.y, params.z));
    this.map.set(Euler, (params: Partial<Euler>) => new Euler(params.x, params.y, params.z, params.order));
  }
}
```

---

**Background**

My original problem is to get a class instance from a plain object recived through a web socket.

For example, a transfered three.js Vector3 looks like this.

```
{x: -251.89716760817976, y: 0, z: 44.7304924070437}
```

To convert it to a `Vector3` instance i have to run

```js
const params: Partial<Vector3> = {x: -251.89716760817976, y: 0, z: 44.7304924070437};
const vec3: Vector3 = new Vector3(params.x, params.y, params.z);
```

Cause i have multiple classes with properties from Three.js and other libraries, i want to outsource the parsing code. My goal is to call something like that in my own transfered classes.

```js
export class Lantern {
  constructor(params: Partial<Lantern> = {}, deserializerService: DeserializerService) {
    Object.assign(this, params);

    this.position = deserializerService.getDeserializeFunction(Vector3)(this.position);
    this.rotation = deserializerService.getDeserializeFunction(Euler)(this.rotation);

    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to have the type `<T>` be on a per-map-key basis.

Unfortunately, the `Map` interface doesn't support this out of the box (and indeed, a proper treatment of the form you're looking for would only be possible with some form of higher-order type support - see eg https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) - although even then, I think what you're asking for would likely require the creation of a new type/interface.

You can however, get what you want with an idea like the following (excusing the naming if it's not right to your use case):

```
type PartialToFull<K> = (params: Partial<K>) => K;

interface DeserializerMap<K> extends Map<K, PartialToFull<K>> {
  get<T extends K>(key: T): PartialToFull<T> | undefined;
  set<T extends K>(key: T, value: PartialToFull<T>): this;
}
```

This defines a map from an instance of `T` to a method `(params: Partial<T>) => T`. (EDIT: I noticed later you actually want the key to be the class / constructor of `T` - so see below for that)

You will likely just want to use `DeserializerMap<any>`, or may want all the types to be of some other certain interface `K` (so I left it in for completeness).

This works by overriding `get` and `set` with the additional knowledge we have about these methods on a per-method basis.

(Note - To easily get these definitions, I copied the type definition of `Map` from `lib.es2015.collection.d.ts` and removed some other methods which didn't need overriding)

Of course - this approach can't be perfect - the best methods like `map.forEach` can assume about the keys are they they are of type `K`, but there's no getting round that :) - but this satisfies your requirements I believe.

## Edit - Oops - you actually want a map from constructors...

Oh wait - I misunderstood:
It appears you want the key to be the "Type" of `T`? In the sense of the object containing the `new` constructor to create a `T` - instead of an instantiation of `T`?

In which case, you will want this:

```
type PartialToFull<K> = (params: Partial<K>) => K;

interface Type<T> extends Function { 
  new (...args: any[]): T; 
}

interface DeserializerMap<K> extends Map<Type<K>, PartialToFull<K>> {
  get<T extends K>(key: Type<T>): PartialToFull<T> | undefined;
  set<T extends K>(key: Type<T>, value: PartialToFull<T>): this;
}

class Vector2 {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  constructor (x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
};

export class DeserializerService {

  private readonly map: DeserializerMap<any> = new Map();

  constructor() {
    this.initMap();
  }

  public getDeserializeFunction<T>(type: Type<T>): PartialToFull<T> {
    const func = this.map.get(type);
    if (!func) {
      throw new Error(`No deserializer found for ${type.name}`);
    }
    return func;
  }

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map.set(Vector2, params => new Vector2(params.x, params.y));
  }
}
```

For an explanation on the definition of the `Type` function, see [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20719#issuecomment-352092588).

Comment: I've improved this answer now to actually give you the answer you were looking for (ie with a key of `Type<T>`, not `T`)

Comment: WOW! Dude, you are absolutly amazing! I still have to look at this closer to understand, but this is absolutly what i wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries.
It turns out modern TypeScript is clever enough to deduce the correct type in the `set` line too, so you can actually just use:
`this.map.set(Vector2, params => new Vector2(params.x, params.y));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type argument on the service and remove the `<T>` from your map definition, otherwise it works as you posted it:

```
//                        v-- Here
class DeserializerService<T> {

  map: Map<T, (params: Partial<T>) => T> = new Map();

}
```

Tests:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const s1 = new DeserializerService<Person>();

s1.map.set(42, null as any); // Error
s1.map.set({ name: 'Bob' }, null as any); // Error
s1.map.set({ name: 'Bob', age: 42 }, null as any); // Works

s1.map.set({ name: 'Bob', age: 42 }, () => ({})); // Error
s1.map.set({ name: 'Bob', age: 42 }, () => ({ name: 'Bob', age: 42 })); // Works
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want the service not just to work with one type. It should work with multiple. To be accurate: With all types implemented in the `initMap()` method

Comment: But your getDeserializeFunction already depends on this T as well, so you have a design problem there too then(?)

Comment: This is probably correct! ..and the reason why i added the original problem. Still don't know how i could use this in an elegant way. Some of the classes are writen by me, some are from different Libraries.